# Help with a SQL query joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

First I will explain the case, I have a table `tbl_game` with a structure as such. This table contains, the time where the game was started and pair playing the game

```
|    id    |     time     |     pair_id    |
-----------+--------------+ ---------------
1          | 123123123    |      1         |
2          | 123168877    |      1         |
```

and I have another table `tbl_throws` which holds the score for each player. In case you are wondering, `this a basic dice rolling game`

```
|   id     |    game_id   |   player_id   |  score  |
-----------+--------------+---------------+---------|
|    1     |    1         |   1           |   2     | 
|    2     |    1         |   2           |   5     |
|    3     |    1         |   1           |   9     |
|    4     |    1         |   2           |   11    |
|    5     |    2         |   1           |   7     | 
|    6     |    2         |   2           |   6     |
```

Now, `id` here is the throw id, not the game id. Here each player with `player_id` 1 and 2 has throws the dice twice and got the respective score as presented all in same game and just one time in another

Now, using these two table, I need to create a record set, that the total score of each player in one game

```
|  game_id   | game_time | player1_total | player2_total|
|------------+-----------+---------------+--------------|
|     1      | 123123123 |     11        |     16       |
|     2      | 123168877 |     7         |     6        |
```

I tried lots of mumbo jumbo queries, but nothing is giving corrent result?
What is the correct query for this?

### Update

Since, most of the answers were bounded by a fact that, player1id and player2id had to be known or fixed.

So may be the information I am about to provide will help to clear the confusion.
there is another table, which holds the information of the player. `tbl_pupil`
Structure is like the following

```
|   id    |   unique_id   | name     |
|---------+---------------+----------|
|   1     |     001       | some     |
|   2     |     002       | another  |
```

and these player are collectively called, a pair in another table `tbl_pair`

```
|   id    |   player1     | player2  |
|---------+---------------+----------|
|   1     |     1         | 2        |

So, now 
select 
    g.id
    g.time
    p1.id as player1id
    p1.name as player1name
    t.score as player1score
    p2.id as player2id
    p2.name as player2name
    t.score as player2score
FROM 
    tbl_game g,
    inner join tbl_pair as pair on g.pair_id = pair.id
    inner join tbl_pupil as p1 on p1.id = pair.player1
    inner join tbl_pupil as p2 on p2.id = pair.player2
    inner join tbl_throw as t on g.id = t.game_id
```

This is my preliminary query, which brings the record set, on a way as such

```
|   id    |   time  |   player1id    |  player1name |   player1score  |   player2id   |    player2name   |  player2score   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1     |   12    |   1            |  some        |   5             |   2           |    another       |  2              |
|   1     |   12    |   1            |  some        |   5             |   2           |    another       |  5              |
|   1     |   12    |   1            |  some        |   9             |   2           |    another       |  9              |
|   1     |   12    |   1            |  some        |   11            |   2           |    another       |  11             |
```

Now I am just showing the results of one game id by the way. I don't save sufficient knowledge, to group the above record into one, with player1 separate sum score in one column and playe2's separate sum of score in another column.

Comment: What type of DB are you using? MSSQL, MySQL?

Comment: @Jon - he added in a comment it's SQL Server, I added the tag.

Comment: One way to approach the problem:  first, get the total score for each player in each game. Then, join that result set to itself, to get the scores of both players on the same row. The answer I posted has an example of this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  tbl_game.id AS game_id, 
  tbl_game.time AS game_time, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN player_id = 1 THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS player1_total, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN player_id = 2 THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS player2_total
FROM tbl_game JOIN tbl_thorws ON tbl_game.id = tbl_throws.game_id
GROUP BY tbl_game.id
```

Comment: Bear in mind this is only valid syntax in `MySQL` since you have a non-aggregated non-grouped field in `Game_time`

Comment: @JNK That's correct. To be portable, we need to add `GROUP BY tbl_game.id, tbl_game.time`

Comment: but how come the player_id is fixed, there are not going to be just 2 players, i just setup an example

Comment: @mrN What you are creating is called a Pivot Table, converting table rows into columns.  Unless you use code to create your SQL dynamically with a for loop, you cannot create a pivot table with an unknown number of columns.  They have to be fixed in the SQL.

Comment: @mrN You can use PHP retrieve the number of players in a game, and build up this query with a loop for the total number of players.

Comment: @mrN - there's not an easy or pretty way to have a variable number of columns in a query like this.  You can add as many as you like and if those players don't exist their score will be 0

Comment: I am doing this is SQL Server for vb.net application so, php is out of option. @JNK, this is a for report generation, so adding multiple players is not a feasible option

Comment: @mrn - well Michael and I showed you how to make the query you are after.  If you need help writing the application side of it please open another question.

Comment: @MrN - Check out my answer, its not dependant on the player IDs being 1 and 2!

Comment: @Jon - I'm not sure how you can say that when you have `Player1` and `Player2` hard coded as field names.  also, he wants more than 2 is what he is saying, not that the numbers will be different.

Comment: @JNK, They're just column names, the query would return the right values for player ids 10 and 25 if they happened to be in the game. in the context of the column headers player1_total means "the total for the first player in the game", not "the total for the player with id = 1"

Comment: I understand that, what I'm saying is it seems that he wants more than 2 players tracked (i.e. add additional fields)

Comment: It is returning false results, like the last row's total is always zero. and the for others also the sum is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inner join the two tables, and aggregate your scores.  To do the basic pivot you are after I used a `CASE` statement to aggregate by player.

```
SELECT  G.Id as Game_Id, 
        G.time as Game_Time,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.Player_id = 1 THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) as Player1_total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.Player_id = 2 THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) as Player2_total
FROM tbl_game G
INNER JOIN tbl_throws T
    ON g.id = t.game_id
GROUP BY g.ID, g.time
```

Comment: @jon - copy paste issue, caught it quick

Comment: This works when the player_id values are specifically 1 and 2, but not more general values for player_id.

Comment: @spencer - yes, that's how the problem was presented in the original post.

Comment: @JNK - is it reasonable to assume that tbl_player will contain only two rows, with id values of 1 and 2?

Comment: @spencer - since OP never indicated that `tbl_player` even **EXISTS** I would say it's not reasonable to assume anything about it.  It seemed from the original post that the player_id was just an ordinal within the game, not a reference to a unique individual.

Comment: @Mrn - I forgot to add `END`, I'll fix it now.

Comment: @JNK given that all of the tables that the OP has shown us have an `id` column as an apparent PK column (eg. `tbl_game.id`) and that other tables have apparent FK columns that reference those PK columns (eg. `tbl_throws.game_id` -> `tbl_game.id`...  I think its eminently reasonable to expect that the `tbl_throws.player_id` column might be a foreign key referencing `tbl_player.id`.

Comment: @mrN - and the field is actually called `t.Player_id`?

Comment: @spencer I don't disagree, I just don't make assumptions about table structure in my answer for a DB object that's not mentioned anywhere in the question

Comment: @JNK: Agreed. But your answer appears to be predicated on the assumption that the player_id values will always be 1 and 2.

Comment: @spencer - it's based on the data provided by the OP

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to some of the other answers, but crucially doesn't depend on the player IDs being 1 and 2.

```
select
    game_id = g.id,
    game_time = g.time,
    player1_total = SUM(case t.player_id when p.player1_id then t.score else 0 end),
    player2_total = SUM(case t.player_id when p.player2_id then t.score else 0 end)
from
    tbl_game g
    join tbl_throws t on g.id = t.game_id
    join ( --Get the player IDs for this game
        select 
            game_id,
            player1_id = MIN(player_id),
            player2_id = MAX(player_id)
        from
            tbl_throws 
        group by game_id
    ) p     
        on p.game_id = t.game_id
group by 
    g.id, g.time
```

---

Just for fun I've generalized the above out to allow more > 2 players:

The 2 CTE tables just show the test data I'm using

```
;WITH tbl_game as (
    select ID = 1, time = 123123123, pair_id = 1
    union select ID = 2, time = 123168877, pair_id = 1
),
tbl_throws as (

select id = 1, game_id = 1, player_id = 1, score = 2
union select id = 2, game_id = 1, player_id = 2, score = 5
union select id = 2, game_id = 1, player_id = 3, score = 5
union select id = 3, game_id = 1, player_id = 1, score = 9
union select id = 4, game_id = 1, player_id = 2, score = 11
union select id = 5, game_id = 2, player_id = 1, score = 7
union select id = 6, game_id = 2, player_id = 2, score = 6
)
select
    game_id = g.id,
    game_time = g.time,
    player1_id = MAX(case x.player_no when 1 then t.player_id else 0 end),
    player1_total = SUM(case x.player_no when 1 then t.score else 0 end),
    player1_id = MAX(case x.player_no when 2 then t.player_id else 0 end),
    player2_total = SUM(case x.player_no when 2 then t.score else 0 end),
    player3_id = MAX(case x.player_no when 3 then t.player_id else 0 end),
    player3_total = SUM(case x.player_no when 3 then t.score else 0 end),
    player4_id = MAX(case x.player_no when 4 then t.player_id else 0 end),
    player4_total = SUM(case x.player_no when 4 then t.score else 0 end)
    /* Add more rows for the number of players permitted in a single game */
from
    tbl_game g
    join tbl_throws t on g.id = t.game_id
    cross apply (
        select player_no = COUNT(distinct player_id) 
        from tbl_throws sub 
        where sub.player_id <= t.player_id 
                and Sub.game_id = t.game_id
    ) x
group by 
    g.id, g.time
```

Comment: why min(player_id) and max(player_id)

Comment: It allows for whatever the two player IDs are - not forcing them to be 1 and 2 - it basically says, treat player 1 as the lower playerid and player 2 as the higher.

Comment: but what if player 1 is 2 and player 2 is 1

Comment: You've got to call the columns something! The results will appear with the lowest playerid's result in player1_total etc.

Comment: I've updated my second query to output the player ID that each score is for as a separate column, that way its possible to stick it all back together.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do pretty much what you want to do.

```
SELECT 
  tbl_game.id as game_id, 
  tbl_game.time as game_time, 
  SUM(player1.score) as player1_total, 
  SUM(player2.score) as player2_total
FROM tbl_game
INNER JOIN tbl_throws player1 ON player1.game_id = tbl_game.id AND player1.player_id = 1
INNER JOIN tbl_throws player2 ON player2.game_id = tbl_game.id AND player2.player_id = 2
GROUP BY tbl_game.id, tbl_game.time
```

Comment: Same issue as Michael's answer, **only valid in MySQL**

Comment: Yes, @Colin, you should add that in other DBMSs, the GROUP BY should be: `GROUP BY tbl_game.id, tbl_game.time`

Comment: A more severe problem is that this query will produce wrong results (mini Cartesian Product issue)

Comment: Good point, I wish I had time to create tables and test this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.game_id
     , t.game_time
     , ( SELECT SUM(t.score)
         FROM tbl_throws AS t
         WHERE t.game_id = g.id
           AND player_id = 1
       ) AS player1_total
     , ( SELECT SUM(t.score)
         FROM tbl_throws AS t
         WHERE t.game_id = g.id
           AND player_id = 2
       ) AS player2_total
FROM tbl_game AS g
```